# Control justification by lines in TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I have TextView:

```
        <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MY TITLE\n\n
first line.................................................... \n
second line.................................................... \n
third line....................................................  \n"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title" />
```

This brings left justify text:

[image]

How to make only first line with text `MY TITLE` centered?

UPD:

Code below still not centers `MY TITLE` string:

```
t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h><center>MY TITLE</center></h>\n" +
                "<p>first line....................................................</p> </br>\n" +
                "<p>second line....................................................</p> </br>\n" +
                "<p>third line....................................................</p> </br>"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can either separate it to **two TextView** or use **Html.fromHtml**

```
 t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<div style='text-align:center' >MYTITLE</center></div>\n" +
            "<p>first line....................................................</p> </br>\n" +
            "<p>second line....................................................</p> </br>\n" +
            "<p>third line....................................................</p> </br>"));
```

Comment: Suddenly I found that in new version of my application I still have not centered `MY TITLE` . More details in UPD